# Custom relationship table in many to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So, I'm writing an e-commerce application and I'm trying to create a many to many relationship between the `Product` and `Size` classes. Entities looks like that:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Size
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSize
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SizeId { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual Size Size { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Normally I wouldn't explicitly create this `ProductSize` table, because EF would create it for me. However, I need the `Amount` column to sit there. Now, for getting info about products with sizes and amounts I have to create a very explicit query (2 joins). If I hadn't manually created the relationship class and just give the `Product` class a virtual `ICollection` of `Size`, getting the complete info would be just a simple matter. So if I had selected a `Product` instance, then all sizes would be loaded into it's `virtual ICollection<Size>`.

The question is - can I achieve the same level of simplicity with the entities structure given above? Instead of writing a 2 join query where I explicitly mention every column I want, and then pack it into some `ViewModel` I'd like to use the simpler syntax for getting a `Product` instance and its related data (so also the data that's sitting in the intermediate table).

Comment: Can't you add a `virtual ICollection<ProductSize>` on both `Product` and `Size` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an [Inverse Navigation Property](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s03.html) to the `ProductSize` from `Product` and `Size` like this:

```
public class Product {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductSize> ProductSizes { get; set; }
}

public class Size {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductSize> ProductSizes { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSize {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SizeId { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual Size Size { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Doing so, you should be able to do like in the following example:

```
from p in Context.Products
where p.ProductSizes.Where(ps => ps.Amount > 0 && ps.Size.Name.Equals("Big")).Any()
select p;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try It tomorrow and then accept your answer.